# mysql - query to get most views in a day based on hour

Tags: mysql

i have the table "visitors"
the fields are

```
    id = integer
    ip = char
    route = char
    created_at = timestamp
```

i want to count group by based on hour, 
i used the query

```
    SELECT * , HOUR(created_at) AS created_hour , COUNT(created_hour)
 FROM `visitors` WHERE created_at > DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY created_hour
```

but i get this error, i can "count" based on "group by"

```
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * , HOUR(created_at) AS created_hour , COUNT(created_hour) FROM `visitors` WHERE created_at > DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY created_hour LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'created_hour' in 'field list'
```

Comment: "*" is nonsensical in this context. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

Change **COUNT(created_hour)** to **COUNT(*)**.

Instead of **WHERE created_at > DATE(NOW())**, use **WHERE created_at < DATE(NOW())**. The current WHERE condition in your query will force nothing to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

You use an alias from the SELECT clause in the same SELECT. This isn't possible, instead you'd have to use this:

```
SELECT HOUR(created_at) AS created_hour
     , COUNT(HOUR(created_at))
FROM `visitors`
WHERE created_at < DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY created_hour
```

Note that in MySQL it is indeed possible to use the alias in the GROUP BY. But it's just not possible to use it in the SELECT.

Also note that `created_at > DATE(NOW())` really doesn't make much sense, unless you're a time traveller.

Also it would be better to use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(HOUR(created_at))`, it's more readable and it does return the same result.